# JMeter cannot assert Http response Code 423

Tags: jmeter, assertion, http-response-codes

I'm trying to assert http response codes in JMeter.
I think this is really simple, but I encountered a problem I cannot fix.

My server can return 2 response codes: 200 and 423.
There is no problem with 200, it just works, but I cannot assert 423, I don't know why.

I tried response assertion with the following configurations:

Field to test: Response Code, 
Pattern Matching Rules: Contains

Patterns to test:
200 - works
423 - does not work
200|423 - 200 works, 423 does not work (wtf?)

I also tried BeanShell Assertion with

```
Failure = !(ResponseCode.contains("200") || ResponseCode.contains("423"));
```

It does not work, too.
Also I tried to match with the response message to contain "Locked" - does not work.
The server Response looks like this:

```
Thread Name: 10 Users, 100 Repeats 1-10
Sample Start: 2017-05-19 13:06:09 MESZ
Load time: 33
Connect Time: 2
Latency: 33
Size in bytes: 333
Sent bytes:768
Headers size in bytes: 333
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): 
Response code: 423
Response message: Locked

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 423 Locked
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Application-Context: application:capacitytest
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 19 May 2017 11:06:08 GMT
Server: Not_available


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

The response code is marked blue for a reason in Sampler Result. Don't know why.
I'm also logging the response code via Beanshell PostProcessor. It is 423...

Finally I'm asking here for your help.
I have no idea what the problem is or could be.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are talking about [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler JMeter automatically threats [HTTP Status Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) above 400 (inclusively) as failed. I would recommend the following setup:

1. Add [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) as a child of your HTTP Request
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Apply to: according to your test scenario
   - Fields to test:

     - `Response Code`
     - **Don't forget to check `Ignore Status` box**
   - Pattern Matching Rules: `Matches`
   - Patterns to Test: `200|423`

Assuming above configuration if the status of your request will be 200 OR 423 - it will pass, otherwise it will get failed by the assertion.

[image: JMeter Response Assertion]

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide for comprehensive information regarding JMeter Assertions.

Comment: Thank you very much! That Ignore-Status-Box I missed was my problem.